# Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing

Tags: exception, akka

when i run my apps in Idea it is good. But when i package and run with java -jar in linux. I got this exception.
[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtCgI.png)

the problem code is

```
val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("src/main/resources/master.conf"))

    master = context.actorSelection(s"akka.tcp://masterSystem@${config.getString("akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname")}:${config.getString("akka.remote.netty.tcp.port")}/user/Master")
```

[the structure of my module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMFKi.png)

Comment: Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka'
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:156)
 at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:149)
 at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:176)
 at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:188)
 at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:250)
 at com.hxdi.server.Worker.preStart(Worker.scala:26)

Answer (score 0):

`src/main/resources` path doesn't exist in your jar and that's by design.

Try first getting your config in your code like this:

`val config = ConfigFactor.load()`

and then pass `java -Dconfig.location=master.conf jar ...` to your program